# How to detect whether the gps is enabled after switchToLocationSettings()?

Tags: ionic-framework, gps, cordova-plugins

I'm working out on the ionic project. I need to get the items based on current district. To get the current district I tried the below.

```
cordova.plugins.diagnostic.isLocationEnabled(function(enabled) {
 alert("Location is " + (enabled ? "enabled" : "disabled"));
 if(!enabled)
  cordova.plugins.diagnostic.switchToLocationSettings();
 var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
 if (navigator.geolocation) {
   navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successFunction, errorFunction);
 } 
 function successFunction(position) {
  var lat = position.coords.latitude;
  var lng = position.coords.longitude;
 }
 function errorFunction(){
  $ionicPopup.alert({
  title:"Alert",
  content:"Geocoder failed"
 });
}
function codeLatLng(lat, lng) {
 geocoder.geocode({'latLng': new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng)}, function(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    if (results[1]) {
      for (var i=0; i<results[0].address_components.length; i++) {
        for (var b=0;b<results[0].address_components[i].types.length;b++) {
          if (results[0].address_components[i].types[b] == "administrative_area_level_2") {
               district= results[0].address_components[i];
          }
        }
      }
     alert(distrcit.long_name);
    }
    else {
      alert("No results");
    }
   }
   else {
    alert("Geocoder Failed");
   }
  });
 }
}, function(error) {
});
```

This code is working fine if the GPS is enabled after switching to location settings. I'm getting the problem when the GPS is not enabled and getting back into the app. How can I detect whether it is enabled or not after moving to location settings and getting back to the app? Even though I referred many posts in StackOverflow, I didn't get the solution what I needed actually. So please help me out in solving it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I detect whether it is enabled or not after moving to location settings and getting back to the app?

You can detect when your app is returned to the foreground using the [resume event](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/events/events.html#resume).

```
function onResume() {
    cordova.plugins.diagnostic.isLocationEnabled(function(enabled) {
        console.log("Location is " + (enabled ? "enabled" : "disabled"));           
        // etc.
    }, function(error) {});
}
document.addEventListener("resume", onResume, false);
```